# ninja and npm_executable-notfound

Tags: node.js, npm, ninja

Trying to build [Tangelo](https://github.com/Kitware/tangelo) from source (first time at this) and I can get 90% of the way through the process with Git Bash and ninja but the final part of the process is not working.

Having cd to my build dir `~/tangelo/build` and ran `ninja` with GitBash I get the following error:

```
$ ninja
[6/135] Installing phantomjs
FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd /D C:\Users\usr\tangelo\build && NPM_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
install phantomjs
$ ninja
[6/132] Installing uglify-js
FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd /D C:\Users\usr\tangelo\build && NPM_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
install uglify-js
'NPM_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[6/132] Installing phantomjs
FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd /D C:\Users\usr\tangelo\build && NPM_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
install phantomjs
'NPM_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[6/132] Creating virtual Python environment
New python executable in C:/Users/usr/tangelo/build/venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools.................done.
Installing pip...................done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:/Python27/python.exe
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have the windows node install from [here](http://nodejs.org/download/) (env var is set to `C:\nodejs` where the node.exe is) and after a re-boot can install the packages that show errors in the code above (uglify-js and phantomjs)

Question is: any ideas how to make ninja understand my node/npm install?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...but other errors to come

I had to run the 'cmake -G Ninja ../' command again before running ninja. Obvious really as i had installed node after the cmake build file were made.

now it seems i'm having problems with ninja and pip

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,
effectivement Tangelo sous Windows a quelques soucis
1) installe et active (running) node dans une fenetre de commandes
2) be carefull, il semble dans '..\tangelo\build\node_modules.bin' (remove dot before bin)

```
ninja --< errors >-- "..\tangelo\build\tangelo\web" ... not of tangelo.js (???)
but in sdist ... finally tangelo.XXX.dev.zip (???)
in gitbash pip install this zip --> localhost:8080 --> surprise !!!
but all not seem allright ( for me, under Win8.1, portable)
```

Comment: thank you for the time, i modified my directory structure to remove the "." before the bin but get the same problem